# asp .net lock action

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking, .net-2.0

In my asp.net 2.0 web application I need to create a new page which will have a button which will allow the user to upload a file. I would like to make this upload action to be used only one at a time, based on some user parameter.

For instance:

1. My website have 100 "users"
2. Each user belong to a "community"
3. If a user start the "upload" operation, no other users from the same community can do that at the same time.

Can this be achieved with lokcing ? (lock) keyword ?

Comment: No, the purpose of `lock` is different. But you can implement this with the help of some db manipulation. let's say you've a table which contains columns i.e community names and status when a person starts downloading, set the status active and when someone else of that same group tries to download at that time, check whether any user of same community is active, if yes, don't allow, otherwise allow.

Comment: I thought about such a solution. But this can lead to inconsistence. What if I set the status "active", and then the connection break ?